# How to sort a vector in R without repeating ranks

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

My question may seem very elementary but i'm getting troubles with it.

Assume we have the following vector :

```
x=c(0.75,0.75,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.25,0.25)
```

I'm willing to sort the vector decreasingly , then getting indices which means :

```
sort.int(x, index.return=TRUE,decreasing=TRUE)
$x
[1] 1.00 1.00 0.75 0.75 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.25 0.25

$ix
[1] 3 4 1 2 5 6 7 8 9
```

However, the expected output should be :

```
y=c(2,2,1,1,3,3,3,4,4)
```

This means :

```
1 is the highest value ----- > 1 
0.75 is the second highest value ----- > 2
0.5 is the third ----- > 3
0.25 is the lowest value -----> 4
```

I also tried :

```
x=c(0.75,0.75,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.25,0.25)

order(unique(sort(x)))

sort(unique(x),decreasing=TRUE)

[1] 1 2 3 4
[1] 1.00 0.75 0.50 0.25
```

But I don't know how to subset from `x` to get the **expected output** `y` .

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` will sort all the values, and use each value once. It seems like you want to ignore the indices of duplicated values after the first. We can use `match` for this, which will always return the index of the first match.

```
match(sort.int(x, decreasing = TRUE), unique(x))
# [1] 2 2 1 1 3 3 3 4 4
```

Comment: Thank you , i tried with replace(x,unique(sort(x)),order(unique(sort(x)))) but it doesn't worked !